# Looking for an extension for Visual Studio Code that provides an interactive live view for html which is connected to the code

Tags: windows, html-editor, visual-studio-code, live-preview

In Adobe Dreamweaver, there is a code, design and live view when designing (html) websites. The design view renders the html but keeps it linked with the code. So you can click on an element you want to edit, and it automatically jumps to the according place in the code.

**Research**

1. Searching for it, all I found was an extension from avocode.com, however, when I open it in Visual Studio Code, it says, that is has been shut down on 1st of January 2023.
2. There is at least the Live Preview extension from Microsoft, but you can't jump to the according code when clicking on the rendered preview.

I am looking for an Visual Studio Code extension or another free software which also supports code highlighting and auto completion for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Five Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server) sounds like what you're looking for:

[image: Five Server]

It can highlight the code you are working on in your browser, it updates your files instantly while typing on your keyboard, and it navigates your browser automatically to the current editing file.

Comment: Yes (and no). Even though this is very nice indeed. I'm actually looking for something that also works the other way: I click in the rendered html (since I can spot the paragraph the fastest there) and I can either edit it directly in the rendered version or the position in the code is marked.

Comment: 2-way highlighting isn't possible yet with Five Server, but there's a discussion item for it: https://github.com/yandeu/five-server/discussions/71. I'd recommend upvoting and adding your thoughts there.

Comment: Done  Thanks for the hint